# Recommended plugins for x64dbg

Tags: debugging, debuggers, x64dbg

I was wondering, as professional reverse engineers - what would be your "must-have" plug ins? Please give a brief description and say how it helps you and possible drawbacks.

The more you can elaborate, the more it will help. I believe that due to google searches, many people will find this thread and will use it to jumpstart their x64dbg usage.

If you need topics to make the answers more specific, I am looking for plugins that

- ease malware analysis
- aid dynamic debugging and
- assist in exploit development

One answer per plugin please.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. There is an issue here, your question is actually more along the lines of eliciting opinions. However, it's borderline. I edited it a bit. As for your Snowman question, please ask it in the chat once you have enough reputation to join there or ask it over on the RCE Subreddit.